# Verify that $M \otimes^L_{(A,A^+)_\blacksquare} (A,A)_\blacksquare \in D(\text{Cond}(B))$ lies in $D(B,\widetilde{B^+[T]})_{\blacksquare}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, condensed-mathematics

I am struggling with verifying a proof in [Scholze's notes on condensed mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf).

Let $(B,B^+)$ be a discrete Huber pair and let $(A,A^+) = (\mathbb{Z}[T],\mathbb{Z})$ and $(A,A) = (\mathbb{Z}[T],\mathbb{Z}[T])$.

In the proof on page 67 of those notes
it is claimed that to verify that $$M \otimes^L_{(A,A^+)_\blacksquare} (A,A)_\blacksquare \in D(\operatorname{Cond}(B))$$ lies in $D(B,\widetilde{B^+[T]})_{\blacksquare},$ one may assume that $(B,B^+)$ is of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ and that $B = B^+[T]$ is a polynomial algebra over $B^+$.

**It is clear to me that we may assume that $(B,B^+)$ is of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$, but why can we assume that $B=B^+[T]?$**

Comment: In general, to check something lies in $D((C,C^+)_\blacksquare)\subset D(\mathrm{Cond}(C))$, one can forget along $D(\mathrm{Cond}(C))\to D(\mathrm{Cond}(C^+))$ and check containment in $D((C^+,C^+)_\blacksquare)$.